# zsh tab completion of filenames at the beginning of the line

Tags: zsh

Is it possible to get TAB to complete files in the current directory even if there is no leading command?  The reason I'd like to do this is that when a suffix alias is defined then a leading command is not necessary.

Comment: Have you tried typing `./` **[Tab]**?

Comment: That cycles between possible directory completions.  I'm hoping for filename completion as the behavior even when the command line in blank.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Bart on zsh-users@zsh.org, this is working:

In one's config files:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _files _expand _complete
```

Which must be *followed* at some point by:

```
autoload -U compinit && compinit -d $ZSHBOOT/zcompdump
```

... the "-d $ZSHBOOT/zcompdump" being specific to me obviously.